# using procedural(sync) mysql functions on Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm making nodejs application with many database call.
and some case I have to use database function step by step.

for example,

```
user_no = getUser(index);
ack = sendJson(user_no, msg);
if(ack) {
  deleteUser(user_no);
}
```

Like above, I have to execute these function procedural.
But function with database query, it run async and order is not guaranteed. when sendJson is called, user_no is undefined. because getUser function is not ended yet.

To solve this problem, I'm using callback function now. But with this solution, I can't fully utilize these functions.

I want make some particular functions to procedural(synchronous)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to turn async functions into sync?

Node.js is a a callback language (eventful too) why are you trying to go against the nature of the language?

Comment: ajax is also async method. but we can use it procedural by add option (async : false). I love the way of Node.js. But some cases, synced procedure is much easy and useful. So I wondered if there's some tip that I can use case by case